# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

Even though there are other questions related to the same error scattered around the web, I'm either being really myopic (in which case I profusely apologise) or my problem is unique.

I'm attempting to modify Jean-Francois Gallant neural network add-on, for a project. I am taking the 'hands-on' approach to this and I have learnt a lot along the way. I have changed the names of the variables and I am almost certain the error I am getting is as a result of that.

I keep getting a 'AttributeError' message from the console whenever I run my script from the Blender Game Engine:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "main", line 112, in 
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'DnpolymeraseNum'

Here is the code I believe is relevant. The code in asterisks is the line with the error:

```
import bge
import math
import mathutils
import nnetga
from random import random
from time import clock 
#¸¸♫·¯·♪¸¸♩·¯·♬¸¸¸¸♫·¯·♪¸¸♩·¯·♬¸¸¸¸♫·¯·♪¸¸♩·¯·♬¸¸¸¸♫·¯·♪¸¸♩·¯·♬¸¸¸¸♫·¯·♪¸¸♩·¯·♬`

input = []
for i in range(2):
    input.append([])
    **for ii in range(bge.logic.DnpolymeraseNum):**
        if i == 1:
            input[i].append([0,0,0,0,0,0])
        if i == 0:
            input[i].append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])`
```

From what I understand the module I've imported is simply not attributed in the module nnetga that is imported. Is there anyway to ensure this happens so I can get rid of this error?

Again, I'm pretty scared to post this question up in case I annoy anyone. If I do I'm sorry, but I'm exhausted.

Comment: Fairly sure you can't [add properties](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html) to `bge.logic`. You probably need to add a game property to the object and add `cont=bge.logic.getCurrentController()` then change your loop to `for ii in range(cont['DnpolyeraseNum']):`

Comment: @sambler Thank you very much, this worked. Please make your answer so I can select it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't [add properties](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html) to `bge.logic`.

To get this to work in the game engine, add a game property to the object and adjust your script to get the controller to access the property.

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()

input = []
for i in range(2):
    input.append([])
    for ii in range(cont['DnpolymeraseNum']):
        if i == 1:
            input[i].append([0,0,0,0,0,0])
        if i == 0:
            input[i].append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])`
```